# Why can't I create process in vs2022

Tags: c++, windows, process

I am new to programming. I want simply create a process , but it always fail.

This is the code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
#include <iostream>

wchar_t* atw(const char* oc)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    return A2W(oc);
}

int main() {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    if (CreateProcess(
        NULL,   
        atw("E:\\AFolder\\AProgram.exe"),
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        false,  
        NULL,  
        NULL, 
        atw("E:\\AFolder"),
        &si, 
        &pi  
    ))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
    ...
}
```

"AProgram.exe" and "AFolder" are just symbols , I am sure they exist and can run.

*Also, my native language is not English, plesae ignore some possible language mistakes and cultural conflict*

Comment: Use [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to find out why it fails.

Comment: One possible issue is that you have not set `si.cb` to the size of the structure after zeroing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid than atw() return a dangling pointer.

check A2W implementation details and warnings from the compiler.

your usage of A2W is wrong.

possible solutions :

```
std::wstring atw(const char* oc)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    return A2W(oc);
}
```

or use A2W directly in main

Comment: Or just replace `atw("E:\\AFolder\\AProgram.exe")` with `L"E:\\AFolder\\AProgram.exe"` since simple hardcoded strings don't need anything more sophisticated.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish - you can't do that. Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for the `lpCommandLine` parameter: "The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."